# What is a word that means regretful and happy at the same time?

Tags: adjectives

I want to know if there is a word that can express regret and joyfulness at the same time.

Comment: Can you describe a situation where this word would be used?  Have you looked up *wistful*?

Comment: @PaulB — Fine. Have deleted mine and will delete this when you've had a chance to read it.

Answer (score 2):

This makes me think of the Portuguese word *saudade*, although that doesn't translate well into any single English word. The closest word I can think of in this regard is *bittersweet*.

Here's the first definition for *bittersweet* in the online MacMillan Dictionary:

> **bittersweet /ˈbɪtərˌswit/** *adjective*
>
> 1. involving feelings of happiness and sadness at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a single word but there is an idiom that is common - **mixed feelings.**

> Mixed Feelings : conflicting feelings or emotions
>
> 'I'm having mixed feelings about the planned trip.'

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mixed%20feelings)

> he's "walking away with mixed feelings and a heavy heart.".

[Chicago Tribune 10th December 2017](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mixed%20feelings)

Answer (score 0):

**poign·ant**
**/ˈpoin(y)ənt/**
*adjective*

evoking a keen sense of sadness or regret.

"a poignant reminder of the passing of time"

synonyms: touching, moving, sad, affecting, pitiful, piteous, pathetic, sorrowful, mournful, wretched, miserable, distressing, heart-rending, tearjerking, plaintive, tragic

"they read aloud the poignant letters written by the victims' children"

archaic

sharp or pungent in taste or smell.

Source: Google Dictionary

Another more commonly used word for the feeling is bittersweet.